# Calling a function on weak pointer

Tags: c++, weak-ptr

I have written the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class Foo
{
    int x = 0;
public:
    int get() const { return x; }
    void set(int x) { this->x = x; }
};

int main(){
    auto sp = shared_ptr<Foo>(new Foo());    
    weak_ptr<Foo> wp;
    wp = sp;
    return 0;
}
```

I want to call the method set on the shared pointer `sp` and also on `wp`, what will be the proper way to call it? I found that `sp->set(5);` works for a shared pointer, but the same doesn't work for the weak pointer.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr is a good overview.  You have to convert it back to a shared pointer with `.lock()`.

Comment: `weak_ptr<Foo> wp;
wp=sp;
auto spt = wp.lock();
spt->set(10);` Is this a correct way?

Comment: Yes, but keep in mind that `spt` could be empty if the original `Foo` object has run out of non-weak references and been deleted, in which case `spt->set(10)` causes undefined behavior.  You should test for this case. Or use the constructor: `shared_ptr spt = wp;` which will throw an exception in that situation.

Comment: well, this question des not show any effort on research, since one can easily find out the answer to this by reading the documentation on cppreference for `std::weak_ptr`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot operate on a weak_ptr.  If the shared_ptr has been deleted, it would be like dereferencing a raw pointer that had been deleted.

Whenever you want to access the pointer contained in it, you would lock it to verify your shared_ptr still exists.

```
if (auto sp = wp.lock()) {
  sp->set(10);
} else {
  // sp no longer exists!
}
```